# Merge lines matching a regex from another file

Tags: regex, unix, merge, awk

I am trying to do the following and I have not yet succeeded. I have two files:

```
header1
data11
data12
data13
header2
data21
data22
data23
header3
data31
data32
data33
header4
data41
data42
data43
...
headerN
dataN1
dataN2
dataN3
```

and the other is

```
header1 num11 num12 num13 num14
header2 num21 num22 num23 num24
header5 num51 num52 num53 num54
header8 num81 num82 num83 num84
...
```

I need to have as output a file that selects the header from file 2 and prints out in the following format (using the above example)

```
header1
data11
num11
num13
data12
data13
header2
data21
num21
num23
data22
data23
header5
data51
num51
num53
data52
data53
...
```

I hope it's clear: I need the header (which should be identified to be common to the two files), the first line of file 1, the second and fourth column of the file 2, the rest of the data of file 1 for that header, and so forth. I have been trying with awk but I have not been able to get what I want from a simple "two files one-liner"  :)

EDIT: Sorry for being misleading. I am not requiring a one-liner. I am just saying I have used a few awk and grep one-liners. I'd like something that works only :) Also, the headers are alphanumeric, with no easy pattern. I need recognition of the whole string.

Comment: It's easy enough to code as a small script, but I don't think this is a 1-liner.  Are we just ignoring columns 3 and 5 from file2?  How many lines are in each of these two files?  And are the "header" and "data" lines easily recognizable in file1?  I.e. in an example, do we match on /^header/ and you'll be able to use that?

Comment: Also, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Sorry for my misleading comment. I am not requiring a one-liner. I have tried a few awk one-liners without too much success. In particular the following
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next} $0 in a' file1 file2 > out
gives me the common strings in the first column of the two files. And I have tried a combination of awk and grep, but with not much success. Sorry for being too vague in my original comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the ugly one liner I came up with (developed on a command line):

```
while read h n1 n2 n3 n4; do echo $h; sed -n -e "/^$h\$/{" -e n -e p -e q -e '}'  file1 ; echo $n1; echo $n3; sed -n -e "/^$h\$/{" -e n -e n -e p -e n -e p -e q -e '}'  file1 ;  done <file2
```

I'm assuming that for every header in `file2` there is a corresponding header in `file1`